# knockout.js change visible status based on if array is empty or not

Tags: knockout.js

I want to be able to have a table show only if there are items in an array. I have simplified down my needs to this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WLapt/1/) example.

JS:

```
var view_model = {
    lines: ko.observableArray([
        {
        content: 'one'},
    {
        content: 'two'},
    {
        content: 'three'},
    {
        content: 'four'},
        ]),
    remove: function(data) {
        view_model.lines.remove(data);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(view_model);
```

HTML:

```
<span data-bind="visible:lines">Lines Exist</span> 
<ul data-bind='foreach:lines'>
    <li>
        <button data-bind="click:$parent.remove">
            Remove
        </button>
        <span data-bind="text:content"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Basically I have a web app where lines can be removed from table. If `array.length == 0`, I want to hide the entire table.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can do this in several ways. The fiddle below uses the containerless bindings to hide the entire table if the lines array has no entries.

http://jsfiddle.net/johnpapa/WLapt/4/

```
<span data-bind="visible:lines">Lines Exist</span> 
<!-- ko if: lines().length > 0-->
<p>Here is my table</p>
<ul data-bind='foreach:lines'>
    <li>
        <button data-bind="click:$parent.remove">
            Remove
        </button>
        <span data-bind="text:content"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
<!-- /ko -->​
```

Comment: Did this actually work at one time? `data-bind="visible:lines"` doesn't appear to work now.  Check your fiddle.  `data-bind="visible:lines().length"` does work, but is less elegant :/

Comment: i just ran the fiddle, removed the lines and it removed the table.

Comment: ... There was an external reference to knockout 2.0 (set on the left hand side), which if removed and replaced with the latest version (inside the javascript config in the editor) made this work.  Not sure where that 2.0 ref  came from, but that appears to have been my problem

Comment: data-bind="visible: lines" does not work if lines are initialized or equalized with an empty array: lines: ko.observableArray([])

Answer (score 8):

Another solution, slight variation on your original attempt:

```
<div data-bind="visible:lines().length">
    <span>Lines Exist</span> 
    <p>Here is my table</p>
    <ul data-bind='foreach:lines'>
        <li>
            <button data-bind="click:$parent.remove">
                Remove
            </button>
            <span data-bind="text:content"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: As of this comment, this works whereas the selected answer does not.

Answer (score 0):

It is considered bad practice to add logic to the html template.
I suggest this solution:

```
<div data-bind="with: lines">     
    <span data-bind="if: length">Lines Exist</span>
    <ul data-bind='foreach:$data'>
        <li>
            <button data-bind="click:$parent.remove">
                Remove
            </button>
            <span data-bind="text:content"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I still see the same logic here?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show message or image like this  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saber13812002/19gLjjgx/) example

```
<div data-bind="visible:lines().length">
    You will see this message only when "lines" holds a true value.
    <img src=""/>
</div>
```

if you want to hide message when table lines datas appeared successfully

```
<div data-bind="visible: !lines().length">
    You will see this message only when "lines" holds a false value.
    <img src=""/>
</div>
```